# UITextField: receive events as not first responder

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to use UITextField as a buffer for input text, however I used custom keyboard and the ios keyboard should not be shown. Therefore, I have resigned first responder(or user interaction disabled) from this text field. The problem is that if I change the value of TextField using direct assignment: testField.text =@"new text", these changes will not be fired by listener (I need an event Editing Change). Is there any ios solution for this problem without defining custom listener?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a notification for your text field:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(yourFunction)
     name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
     object:self.yourTextField];
```